# Extjs 4.1 - Hidden Window and show it again fail within MessageBox

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I define a window like **http://jsfiddle.net/KABQD/**

Here is my window

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'window',   
    width:200,
    height:100,

    modal:true,
    closable:false,
    tbar: [{    
        text:'hide',
        handler:function(){
            this.up('window').hide();
        }
    }]
});
```

And a button. If click button my window will be create and show for first time. If click button again then window will show. But it fail when i using Messagebox. 

 How to fix that thank

Here is my button

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    visible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        var x = 0;
        Ext.WindowManager.each(function(win) {
            x = 1;
            win.show();
        });
        if (x == 0){
            // if don't use MessageBox then will working
            Ext.MessageBox.show({ 
                msg: 'wait...', 
                progressText: 'Loading...', 
                width:300, 
                wait:true, 
                waitConfig: {interval:200}
            });
            //Ext.Ajax.request({
                //url : 'example.php'
                //,success: function(response, opts) {
                    var a = new MyWindow();
                    a.show();
                    Ext.MessageBox.hide();  
                //}
            //});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `WindowManager` can't see your object. You should instantiate your MyWindow object with an id, like this `new MyWindow({id: 'NewWindow'});` And then you can catch your object in `WindowManager` and call the `show()` method.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/A92yN/3/

Full code:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'window',   
    width:200,
    height:100,

    modal:true,
    closable:false,
    tbar: [{    
        text:'hide',
        handler:function(){
            this.up('window').hide();
        }
    }]
});
Ext.onReady(function () {
      Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        visible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            var x = 0;
            Ext.WindowManager.each(function(win) {
                x = 1;
                var win = Ext.getCmp('NewWindow');
                win.show();
            });
            if (x == 0){
                // if don't use MessageBox then will working
                Ext.MessageBox.show({ 
                    msg: 'wait...', 
                    progressText: 'Loading...', 
                    width:300, 
                    wait:true, 
                    waitConfig: {interval:200}
                });
                //Ext.Ajax.request({
                    //url : 'example.php'
                    //,success: function(response, opts) {
                        var a = new MyWindow({id: 'NewWindow'});
                        a.show();
                        Ext.MessageBox.hide();  
                    //}
                //});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just understand why. MessageBox and window in Extjs both are window and both're hidden in my problem. But how to know to catch and show real my window? or how to close() MessageBox (not hide)

Comment: i using destroy() my MessageBox and everything working thank for help :)